# How can I group select values in a single select as array in laravel mysql?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to get this from a query using eloquent.

```php
$data = [
    "user" => [
        "img_profile" => "profileimage",
        "username" => "myusername"
    ],
    "description" => "postdescription",
    "img" => "postimg"
];
```

I managed to get this using the following php code, but I want to get this from the query, is there any way?

```php
$posts = posts::join('business', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'business.user_id')
    ->join('cities', 'business.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
    ->select(
        'posts.description as description',
        'posts.img as img',
        'business.name as name',
        'business.img_profile as img_profile',
        'business.username as username'
    )
    ->where('business.city_id', $city)
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->limit('10')
    ->get();

foreach($posts as $post){
    $data[$i] = [
        "user" => [
            "username" => $post->username,
            "img_profile" => $post->img_profile
        ],
        "description" => $post->description,
        "img" => $post->img
    ];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: How did you get `$posts`?

Comment: @miken32  $posts =  posts::join('business','posts.user_id','=','business.user_id')
        ->join('cities','business.city_id','=','cities.id')
        ->select('posts.description as description','posts.img as img',
        'business.name as name','business.img_profile as img_profile','business.username as username')
        ->where('business.city_id',$city)
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->limit('10')
        ->get();

Comment: Well the first red flag I see is no relationships set up between models. You shouldn't have to manually join in your `business` table, rather something like `Post::with("business", "city")`. Eloquent can do this, but you're not going to be able to do what you want with just query builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key to your problem is that you think you are using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent), but you are not – you are using [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries). Eloquent handles the relationships between your models so you never have to think about tables. If you are using `join()` then you're not using Eloquent.

From what I can see, you're starting with a `City`, selecting `Business` related to this city, and then selecting 10 random `Post` from the `Business`? Things are a bit unclear since you seem to be using non-conventional table and column names, but hopefully this will give you an idea where to start.

Step one is setting up a relationship; in addition to typical "`City` has many `Business`" and "`Business` has many `Post`" you'll want to set up a direct relationship between `City` and `Post` like this:

```php
class City extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Post::class, Business::class);
    }
}
```

Once that relationship is in place, you should be able to get what you're looking for with something like this:

```php
$city = City::find($city_id);
$data  = $city
    ->posts()
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->limit(10)
    ->with("business:id,name,img_profile,username")
    ->get();
```